# Is there a code to call a function along with every function in the script?

Tags: javascript

Is there a code to call a "certain function" whenever any function is called? (rather than writing the funtion every time)
FOR JAVASCRIPT (WEB)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Are you trying to trigger a function call when another is called? It would be helpful to add code samples showing what you have tried.

Comment: Not trivially, no, but it depends how you're referencing the functions. If they're attached to an object you could pass that object in, wrap all the functions, and you're done. There are likely AOP package available that would ease the task.

Comment: Literally taken, not possible, that would lead to infinite calls of functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle situations like this, there might be a better approach but this way gives me power to decide which function to call and when.

```
const EventEmmiter = require('events');

class MyEmmiter extends EventEmmiter {};

const myEmmiter = new MyEmmiter();

myEmmiter.on('call-foo', ()=> {
    foo();
});

function foo() {
    //to be called
};

function callingFoo() {

    myEmmiter.emit('call-foo');

};
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely sure if there is a way for a function to be called at every instance functions are called but depending on what you are trying to do you could play around with callbacks. You could pass functions into the global function and execute them along with the code you want to always run.

```
function one() {
    console.log('I am function one');
}

function two() {
    console.log('I am function one');
}

function alwaysCall(f) {
    f();
    console.log('this happens as you call functions');
}

alwaysCall(one);
alwaysCall(two);
```

Comment: You'd need to take parameters into account, but this doesn't seem worthy of a downvote.